# Field evaluated to the values (0.0), not of type SHORT-FLOAT

Tags: types, common-lisp, record

I recently found out that it's possible to add type-restrictions to structs, however for whatever reason, it doesn't allow `0.0` as a legal default value for short floats, yet it does allow `100.0`.

I get the following error when I try to run `make-ship` to make an instance of a `ship` structure in CLisp:

```
[4]> (make-ship)

*** - THE: #:ENERGY evaluated to the values (0.0), not of type SHORT-FLOAT
The following restarts are available:
ABORT          :R1      Abort main loop
```

Can someone explain what exactly is going on, and why I'm not allowed to use 0.0?

Here's the code that misbehaves:

```
(defstruct ship
  location ;; fields like these have an undecided type at the moment
  (energy 0.0 :type short-float)
  cargo
  crew
  shields
  (hull-integrity 100.0 :type short-float))
```

Comment: Not a full explanation, but have you tried the various suffixes, e.g., `0.0d`, etc.?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I didn't know suffixes were even a thing...

Comment: See http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_cbb.htm. I think s should work.

Answer (score 4):

Common Lisp has syntax for different kinds of floats,  described in [2.3.2.2 Syntax of a Float](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_cbb.htm). one of the examples shows how to write 0 as a short float: **0s0** and **0.0s0** both work.

Comment: Weird thing is that the code I used is taken straight from the struct examples in the hyperspec

Comment: Can't check right now, but take a look into default float formats, etc. I expect that there's some flexibility on what the system can read a float in as when the type isn't specified. So the example in the spec might be legal, but not mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

When there is no [exponent marker](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_e.htm#exponent_marker), or "e" is used at the exponent marker, then the type of the floating point number read in is determined by the global variable [*READ-DEFAULT-FLOAT-FORMAT*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_rd_def.htm), which defaults to [SINGLE-FLOAT](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_short_.htm#single-float), which is not necessarily a SHORT-FLOAT.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that CLisp distinguishes between `SINGLE-FLOAT` (`0.0` or `0.0e0`) and `SHORT-FLOAT` (`0s0`). Thus, the call `(make-ship)` fails. To fix: either need to replace `0.0` and `100.0` with `0s0` and `100s0` respectively or replace all `SHORT-FLOAT`'s with `SINGLE-FLOAT`'s.

PS: in both SBCL and ECL the example works as is as they both don't distinguish between these floats.